# PHP internal development question, want to extend the curly syntax with quoting functionality

Tags: php, customization, php-7.4

I know this is a bit offtopic to SO given that I have no code and my question is abstract.

I want to add a functionality into the PHP language:
Existing functionality:

```
$var=123;
$string = "This is a {$var} variable";
```

Wanted new functionality for SQL variables:

```
$var="asd' union ()";
$string = "This is a {(QUOTE)$var} quoted variable";
```

Or:

```
$var="asd' union ()";
$string = "This is a {QUOTE($var)} quoted variable";
```

The idea is to extend the string curly syntax to support either a function or some hardcoded function to quote variables.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to write a php module/extension that will provide such functionality ?
If so, where do I have to look to get started quickly ?

**Solution**

```
function _quote($v) { return strtoupper($v); }
$_Q = '_quote';
$string = "This is an {$_Q($var)} integer";
echo $string;
```

I guess that's closest of what I want without having to hack php itself

Comment: Why? You should be using prepared statements, there's no need for this.

Comment: Because I would like it that way and I dislike prepared statements or prequoted strings.

Comment: Why not abstract this away into a function, then? You can parse the string, find the functions and variables you want, perform the operations dynamically in memory, and then pass the results into a prepared statement, all without ever touching the prepared statement directly. You also avoid the need to maintain a potentially dangerous extension that could be susceptible to breaking with any new release of PHP. A function like `createStatement('This is a {QUOTE($var)} quoted variable')` would be very reasonable.

Comment: Just to be clear this **cannot** be an extension. You aren't extending PHP. You are literally changing it. Because the PHP Parser has to be compiled from itself (yes, we compile the compiler), you can't simply provide a shared object to do this. You have to build the entire php-src tree from scratch including the parser itself (which is prepackaged with php normally).

Comment: @B.Fleming I am literally doing that, though it's performance hungry as it has to protect against parser-injections. (Imagine $var contains the characters ')}', it takes quote some overhead to detect and handle that)
 To make that performant it would need to be written as external module. I thought having it directly within PHP syntax would be more elegant.

Sherif: thanks, I feared that's the case

Comment: @John Consider tokenizing rather than interpolating, then. Create a `MyCustomStatement` object, do `MyCustomStatement::add('var', $var)`, then `MyCustomStatement::create('This is a {QUOTE($var)} quoted variable')`. The single quotes will prevent interpolation and you use the `$var` token within the string to locate the value added from `add()`. There are plenty of ways to do this without attempting to modify the core language.

Comment: More importantly, lines of code are a non-issue. Maintainability and security are more important. It's far better to have "bloaty" code that does the job well, securely, in a way that is easier to understand, than it is to have shorter code that sacrifices any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking your presented use case is the least useful, since you should be using parameterized queries anyway. You might be after solving the wrong problem. However, to extend the language itself one would have to modify the parser. That entails knowing [YACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) as well as some knowledge of PHP internals. This is by no means a trivial thing in  your case particularly because you aren't just modifying how PHP parses the string, but also how it compiles the opcodes that entail function execution.

You can [read a detailed blog post on how to approach your idea in Nikita's blog](https://nikic.github.io/2012/07/27/How-to-add-new-syntactic-features-to-PHP.html) if you're curious. Though I'd posit there is a much easier solution to your immediate problem of escaping strings in SQL than trying to modify the entire PHP langauge.

---

Giving a more lengthy explanation of the innards of how the PHP parser works in this answer would be exhaustive. Which is why I'm linking to the most technically correct explanation of the problem that I'm aware of.

---

> ## Important side note
>
> Just to be clear this **cannot** be an extension. You aren't extending PHP. You are literally changing it. Because the PHP Parser has to be compiled from itself (yes, we compile the compiler), you can't simply provide a shared object to do this. You have to build the entire php-src tree from scratch including the parser itself (which is prepackaged with php normally).
>
> The consequence of this is that you have now forked your own implementation of the PHP language that is no longer compatible with defacto PHP.
>
> In other words... *you own it for life*.

Comment: Given your Sidenote, I'll not go that path ;)  
That's what I feared when I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Please please please use prepared statements for SQL. Also, read this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Disliking prepared statements is not a reason to not use them, instead maybe find a trusted library that handles them better, does it differently, or maybe even switch to an ORM.

To focus more on your question, it might be easier to accomplish what you want by using something like Mustache, forking it, and layering in your customization. https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

I highly doubt you will be able to build a module to provide this sort of functionality. Most modules provide a very specific/isolated additional functionality. I can't think of a module that modifies how native language constructs behave. To do that, you'd need to modify PHP Core itself, which means writing some C, and then deploying a PHP version that isn't compatible with anything else out there.

Comment: I'm coming from a different world than the average sql code written in PHP, I'm dealing with files that contain hundreds of different queries.
Parametrized code is bloaty, when a single line of code could do it you'll suddenly have 10 lines.
It's performance benefits are irrelevant in comparison the the performance issues inside the sql server when dealing with big data.
And given proper quoting there is no security benefit.
Currently I use an own parser that basically does what I want to do PHP internally

Some fool is giving every answer here -1, I'm sorry. And thanks for your response